# Executing cURL upon Git Push

Tags: git, curl, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm very new to running a Git server, and I needed to trigger a Jenkins build upon pushing to Git.

A tutorial says to do this command:

> curl http://[jenkins]/git/notifyCommit?url=[job]

but it doesn't tell you how to trigger that cURL upon a git push. Am I reading this wrong? If not, how do I do so? If I am, what am I supposed to do with this command?

Answer (score 1):

I found it out by searching around the repo... you need to make the file

> /path/to/repository/.git/hooks/post-commit

and add

```
 #!/bin/sh
 curl http://[jenkins]/git/notifyCommit?url=[job]
```

Comment: Well you if you wanted to trigger after the push, not commit, it needs to be in post-receive hook for that repo.

Comment: @DanilaLadner if you want to put that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: No worries. That is fine.